# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input and Java null exception error for devbridge autocomplete

Tags: java, jquery, json, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used the DAO several times, so I dont think the error is comming from there, I think the error might be because of the JSON. I am new to JSON.

GLASSFISH SERVER OUTPUT: NULL EXCEPTION.. When printing SupplierID INT, it prints null

HTML CODES

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="search" id="autocomplete-ajax"  placeholder="Enter Country name"/>
    </div>
    <div id="selection" ></div>
</div>
```

SERVLET CODES

```
try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */

        String supplierID = request.getParameter("search");
        System.out.println("Hello from Get Method: " + supplierID);
        int supplierIDInt = Integer.parseInt(supplierID);

        ArrayList<RefSupplier> RefSupplierList = new RefSupplierDAO().getSupplier(supplierIDInt);
       Gson gson = new Gson();
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < RefSupplierList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            try {
                obj.put("supplierID", RefSupplierList.get(i).getSupplierID());
                obj.put("itemCode", RefSupplierList.get(i).getItemCode());
                obj.put("itemName", RefSupplierList.get(i).getItemName());
                obj.put("companyName", RefSupplierList.get(i).getCompanyName());
                obj.put("companyAddress", RefSupplierList.get(i).getCompanyAddress());
                obj.put("contactPerson", RefSupplierList.get(i).getContactPerson());
                obj.put("contactNumber", RefSupplierList.get(i).getContactNumber());
                array.put(obj);

            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(GetSuppliersAndItemForSuppliersServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
             String json = gson.toJson(array);
         System.out.println(json);
        response.getWriter().write(json);

    }
```

JQUERY CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#autocomplete-ajax").autocomplete({
            serviceUrl: 'GetSupplierItemForBillOfMaterialsServlet', //tell the script where to send requests
            type: 'POST',
            onSelect: function (suggestion) {
                $('#selection').html('You selected: ' + suggestion.value + ', ' + suggestion.data);
            },
            showNoSuggestionNotice: true,
            noSuggestionNotice: 'Sorry, no matching results',
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know on what line the error is being thrown? What does the logging and `System.out.println` output show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default from devbridge plugin should be query not search

String supplierID = request.getParameter("query"); right code below